# prevent a Broadcast Receiver from being killed by recent apps

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In my app,I'm using a `Broadcast Receiver` to detect arrived sms messages... 
when my app is running,works well... 
**but after killed by recent apps**,when an sms with `MessageBody:"silent"` arrived ,my app crashes...! 
// `silent` is an action in my SMS BroadcastReceiver ...

Here is my code:

> Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

> BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static String senderTel;
public static String messageBody;




    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");

        SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);
        senderTel = sms.getOriginatingAddress();
        messageBody = sms.getMessageBody().toLowerCase().trim();




        if(messageBody.equals("silent")){
            G.AudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
            G.AudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
            Toast.makeText(G.currentActivity, "silent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

> G :

```
public class G extends Application {

    public static Context           context;
    public static Activity currentActivity;

 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
        AudioManager= (AudioManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

So I tried to use service and alarm manager but they failed

```
Intent intent = new Intent(G.context, SmsReceiver.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(G.context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        G.alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 3000, pendingIntent);
```

**I want to keep my broadcast receiver alive even after the app kill by recent apps or force close...** 
Is it necessary to use `Service` ...? 


Thank you for any help you can provide

Comment: post your manifest please

Comment: If the user force stops your app, your `BroadcastReceiver` will not be triggered again until the user runs your app himself again. This behaviour was added in Android 3.0. There is nothing you can do to prevent this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing:

```
Toast.makeText(G.currentActivity, "silent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

to

```
Toast.makeText(context, "silent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The application is being killed, not the BroadcastReceiver. The receiver is invoked when it is needed by android. The solution here is to use the context that is provided by the method parameters instead of the activity which is possible to be null.

If you wanted to only show the toast when the app is opened, consider adding a check to see if currentActivity is null (assuming it is assigned onStart and cleaned onStop), or registering the receiver in the activity.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I believe the main issue here is that in your `BroadcastReceiver`, you are calling a reference from your application (`G.currentActivity`), and since the application is dead, that makes the `BroadcastReceiver`crash. The problem is not that your BroadcastReceiver is not working...

Comment: Pretty much this. If your BroadcastReceiver is defined in your app and your app is closed, the BroadcastReceiver is released along with all of the other app resources. The way to receive a broadcast without the app running is through a Service.

Comment: @drschultz provided that the user has launched the app at least once, android will always invoke receivers declared in the manifest.

Comment: @RobVoisey Yes, you are correct. Sorry, I wasn't very clear in my first statement. What I meant was that if your BroadcastReceiver was actually defined fully inside your Activity or another class, it will not run apart from the app. Additionally, referencing another class in your app (in this case, the "G" class) from inside the BroadcastReceiver will also cause issues, as Mateus mentioned above. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @ RobVoisey Thank you guys,so helpful ;)